# Browserify-hogan .render() returns empty string

Tags: javascript, mustache, browserify

Does any of you have experience working with gulp + browserify + browserify-hogan?

I'm trying to include a mustache template into my browserified JS controller, and apparently it works fine, my gulp task runs without an error, and I can require the template in the js file:

`var tpl = require('./my-template.mustache');`

But when I call `tpl.render()` all I get is an empty string. I've looked into my compiled js file, and the transformed mustache template looks like this:

`var t = new (require('hogan.js/lib/template')).Template(function(c,p,i){var _=this;_.b(i=i||"");_.b("// my-template.mustache");_.b("\n" + i);_.b("test");_.b("\n" + i);_.b("\n" + i);_.b("\n");return _.fl();;});module.exports = {  render: function () { return t.render.apply(t, arguments); },  r: function () { return t.r.apply(t, arguments); },  ri: function () { return t.ri.apply(t, arguments); }};`

Looking at this I'd assume everything is fine as my .mustache file contains a single line with the string `test` in it. But I don't understand why render() doesn't return anything.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with browserify-hogan being incompatible with the recent version of hogan.js.

Make sure you've got a v2 version of hogan.js installed using `npm install hogan.js@~2`.